# Variation in alignment on resize with dimensions in '%'s & pixels

Tags: html, css

When I give width & height in pixels, the alignment remains intact even after resize. But if given in %'s it gets disturbed like one div overflows into another & get mixed up with each other.Why does this happen & what are the cases in which giving the dimensions in %'s is better than giving in pixels. Is there any other best method other in pixels.

If we take any website or css template, for most of them width is given in pixels, not as percentages & margin as 0px auto, for auto adjust & alignment.Why it becomes so messy when margin, padding , width given in  %'s?

Comment: add some example? % width depend on outer container, outer container can be fixed width then inner can work according to %

Comment: Does fixed width mean container's width can't be increased or decreased? How to declare so as fixed? Is it possible to minimize if width is fixed? I don't mean width is fixed it has to change on resize & different resolution.